# Constraint in a 2D plot with Legend

Tags: plotting, legending

I have the following plot:

```
Plot[Table[C*r^2 + 2 C, {C, {25, 100, 150, 300}}] // Evaluate,
     {r, 0, 1000}, 
     PlotLegends ->LineLegend[{25, 100, 150, 300}, LegendLabel -> C,
             LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.2], Bold, 10}, LegendFunction -> "Frame"], 
     AxesLabel -> {r, Plot}, 
     PlotLabel -> "Plot"]
```

But I need to include a constraint: `r >= C.` So when `C` is `300`, the plot should show only for `r = 300` to `r = 1000`.

How should I modify this code?

Comment: Change the first argument in `Table` to `ConditionalExpression[C*r^2 + 2 C, r >= C]`?

Comment: it worked! Shame on me, it was too easy. thank you!

Comment: my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se. I posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[Table[ConditionalExpression[C*r^2 + 2 C, r >= C], 
          {C, {25, 100, 150, 300}}] // Evaluate, 
     {r, 0, 500}, 
     PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{25, 100, 150, 300}, LegendLabel -> C, 
                               LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.2], Bold, 10}, 
                               LegendFunction -> "Frame"], 
     AxesLabel -> {r, Plot}, 
     PlotLabel -> "Plot"]
```

[image]